# VisualStudioCode. SFDX: Authorize an Org. Time out error

Tags: salesforcedx-cli-auth

Starting SFDX: Authorize an Org

19:18:42.991 sfdx force:auth:web:login --setalias vscodeOrg --instanceurl https://login.salesforce.com --setdefaultusername
spawn UNKNOWN
CLIError: timed out
at Object.error (C:\Users***\AppData\Local\sfdx\client\7.163.0-ea5a9c6\node_modules@oclif\core\lib\errors\index.js:28:15)
at C:\Users***\AppData\Local\sfdx\client\7.163.0-ea5a9c6\node_modules@oclif\core\lib\cli-ux\index.js:25:66
at async flush (C:\Users***\AppData\Local\sfdx\client\7.163.0-ea5a9c6\node_modules@oclif\core\lib\cli-ux\index.js:121:9) {
oclif: { exit: 2 },
code: undefined
}

Comment: Hi Dhiren, welcome to SFSE. Please take a moment to scroll through the [tour] and read [ask]. As written, this post does not make clear what you are asking. Please [edit] its content to include a question.

Answer (score 1):

There can be multiple reasons for timeout:

- network traffic between the environment you execute this command in and salesforce is not whitelisted
- programs in the environment you are in blocks it (like antivirus)
- Internal Salesforce issue either with an instance or SFDX CLI version - try using a different version
- inspect logs in `%HOMEPATH%/.sfdx/sfdx.log` - maybe you will find the root cause there
- ask colleagues to check if they are having the same issue with their users. Try using other credentials.
- Try looking for a similar issue on SFDX CLI [Github page](https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues). If there is nothing post your question with details there.
- Is the same issue occurring when you [authenticate using jwt](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_auth_jwt_flow.htm)?